Why the QgsFields.setLength(length) method does not work in PyQGIS 3?
I have a problem with changing the length of the field.
Here is a simple example:
 pole1 = "poznamka"
 pole2 = "porast"
 lenght = 20
 for poleExistujuce in layer_provider.fields():
        if poleExistujuce.name() == pole1 or poleExistujuce.name() == pole2:
              print("pred zmenou", poleExistujuce.name(), poleExistujuce.length())
              poleExistujuce.setLength(dlzka)
              print("po zmene", poleExistujuce.name(), poleExistujuce.length())
 
 editLayer.updateFields()

 print([field.length() for field in layer_provider.fields()])

The result is as follows:
pred zmenou poznamka 254 po zmene poznamka 20

pred zmenou porast 254 po zmene porast 20

[10, 10, 254, 254]

The individual fields were updated but after the
editLayer.updateFields()

command, the field lengths were returned. Where can the error be?
